# Tkinter on python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using this online virtual machine to practise python. but I am getting this error when I try to use tinter:

```
import sys 
from tkinter import *
MGu = TK()
MGu.geometry('450x450')
```

error:

```
sh-4.3$ python main.py                                                                                                                                 
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                     
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>                                                                                                                  
    import tkinter                                                                                                                                     
ImportError: No module named tkinter                                                                                                                   
sh-4.3$ python main.py                                                                                                                                 
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                     
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>                                                                                                                  
    from tkinter import *                                                                                                                              
ImportError: No module named tkinter
```

---

Comment: try to check for spelling errors **tkinter**?

Comment: you aren't going to be able to use tkinter in an online VM. Tkinter requires access to a display, which it can't get via a browser and web server.

Comment: Are you using Python 2? If yes, then use `Tkinter` instead of `tkinter`.